# Add tag synonym [int] --> [integer]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

[int](/questions/tagged/int) has 1,703 questions, [integer](/questions/tagged/integer) has 2,215, and they seem pretty much interchangeable to me.

Another one that is related is [isinteger](/questions/tagged/isinteger) (10 questions), although I'm not sure it is similar enough to be considered a synonym.

One more: [numeric](/questions/tagged/numeric) (392) and [numerical](/questions/tagged/numerical) (203).

Comment: They aren't always the same, though. In java, they have quite different meanings (one is a primitive, and the other is an object)

Answer (score 2):

As [Richard J. Ross III](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151015/richard-j-ross-iii) points out, in Java an [int](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is a primitive datatype, while [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) is a class derived from the `Number` class. They are two different concepts, and there is the need of using two different tags, as a question about the `Integer` class is not the same as a question about the primitive datatype.

In PHP, [is_integer()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-integer.php) is the function that checks if the datatype of a value/variable is an integer. Probably, it would be better to use [is-integer](/questions/tagged/is-integer), or [is-int](/questions/tagged/is-int) as `in_integer()` is an alias for `is_int()`. I cannot say if there is the need of having [isinteger](/questions/tagged/isinteger), but for sure [isinteger](/questions/tagged/isinteger) is not a synonym of [integer](/questions/tagged/integer).

[numeric](/questions/tagged/numeric) and [numerical](/questions/tagged/numerical) are similar enough; IMO, there isn't the need of having two tags, when they are used with the same meaning.